# Why does getline() get the preceding line?

Tags: c, input, getline

```
bdoetsch@Kaladin:~/Documents/School$ ./shell
Shell(pid = 6955) 1> ls
command: ls
argv[i] = ls
argv[i] = ./shell
Parent says 'child process has been forked with pid=6956'
./shell
Parent says 'wait() returned so the child with pid=-1 is finished'
Shell(pid = 6955) 2>
```

This is homework I am working on, but I am a little stumped.

Hi, I am trying to write a shell program and I don't understand  why       getline is getting the preceding line of input.

plus the program will execute 'ls -al, 'pwd and a few others.  but not just ls.

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int tokenizer(char *str,char **argv);
void doCommand(char **argv);

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    char *command;
    int Num_bytes_read;
    size_t nbytes = 60;
    int NumCommand = 0;
    char **argv;

    int NumOfArgs;

    command = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
    command = NULL;
    while(1)
    {   
        NumCommand++;
        printf("Shell(pid = %d) %d> ",getpid(),NumCommand);

        fflush(stdin);

        Num_bytes_read = getline(&command,&nbytes,stdin);

        printf("command: %s",command);        
        if(Num_bytes_read == -1)
        {
            printf("\n ERRor\n");
        }
        else
        {  
            int x = tokenizer(command,argv);
            int i;        

            for (i = 0; i < (x+1); ++i)
                printf ("argv[i] = %s\n",argv[i]);
            //if (strcmp(argv[0], "quit")){
            //break;
            //}
            doCommand(argv);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int tokenizer(char *str, char **argv)
{
    //const char s[2] = " "; 
    char ** res  = NULL;
    char * p    = strtok (str, " \n");
    int n_spaces = 0, i;
    while (p) 
    {
        res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);
        if (res == NULL)
            exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */
        res[n_spaces-1] = p;
        argv[n_spaces-1]= res[n_spaces-1];

        p = strtok (NULL, " \n");
    }
    // realloc one extra element for the last NULL 

    res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
    res[n_spaces] = 0;

    argv = res;
    return n_spaces;
}      

void doCommand(char **argv)
{
    pid_t  pid;
    pid_t cpid; /* Pid of child to be returned by wait. */
    int fd[2];  // dual pipeline
    int status; /* Exit status of child. */

    int nbytes;
    int commandStatus;

    pipe(fd);

    pid = fork();   // Preceding with fork]
    if (pid < 0) 
    {   
        printf("forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)     // fork for the child
    {    
        close(fd[0]); // close up reader side of pipe

        cpid = getpid();  

        /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */  
        write(fd[1], &cpid,sizeof(cpid));
        //argv[0] = "ls";
        //argv[1] = NULL;
        commandStatus = execvp(*argv, argv);
        if (commandStatus < 0)  /* execute the command  */
        {    
            printf("Try again, command failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if (pid > 1)                // fork for the parent
    {  
        close(fd[1]);

        /* Read in the child pid from the pipe */
        nbytes = read(fd[0], &cpid , sizeof(cpid));
        printf("Parent says 'child process has been forked with pid=%ld'\n",(long)cpid);
        wait(NULL);
        cpid = wait(&status);      /* wait for completion  */

        printf("Parent says 'wait() returned so the child with pid=%ld is finished'\n",(long)cpid);
    }
}
```

Comment: `command = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);` not required.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` not good.

Comment: `fflush()` is not defined for input stream (or input/output stream where the last operation was input).

Comment: `argv` is never initialized and there is a access `argv[n_spaces-1]= res[n_spaces-1];` leading to UB

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr and should be useful.  For example: `if(pid < 0) { perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `argv` is not really initialized, because you are altering the local pointer in `tokenizer()`, instead of the pointer in `main()`.

What you have to do is pass `argv`'s address instead of the pointer itself, and then change `tokenizer()` like this

```
int tokenizer(char *str, char ***argv)
{
    char ** res      = NULL;
    char *  p        = NULL;
    int     n_spaces = 0;

    if ((str == NULL) || (argv == NULL))
        return 0;

    p     = strtok (str, " \n"); 
    *argv = NULL;
    while (p)
    {
        res = realloc (*argv, sizeof(char *) * ++n_spaces);
        if (res == NULL)
        {
            free(*argv);
            return 0;
        }
        res[n_spaces - 1] = p;
        *argv             = res;
        p                 = strtok (NULL, " \n");
    }
    res = realloc (*argv, sizeof(char *) * (n_spaces + 1));
    if (res == NULL)
    {
        free(*argv);
        return 0;
    }
    res[n_spaces] = 0;
    *argv         = res;

    return n_spaces;
}
```

and in main

```
int x = tokenizer(command, &argv);
/*                         ^ address of argv */
```

you never checked the last `realloc` too, so I fixed some of other things I believe you was doing a little bit unsafe.

`exit()` on `malloc`/`realloc` failure is not really necessary in your case, you can just `free()` the already alloced pointer and just return `0`, then handle that in `main()`.

Also, I recommend the usage of the `const` qualifier wherever it makes sense, for example

```
void doCommand(const char *const *argv)
```

And also, don't `fflush()` `stdin` it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Iharob,  what program did you use to format my code so nicely?

Comment: @BrianDoetsch None, I just did it my self.

Comment: @BrianDoetsch where? did you copy and paste the function?

Comment: shell.c: In function ‘main’:
shell.c:45:32: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘tokenizer’ from incompatible pointer type
      int x = tokenizer(command,&argv);
                                ^
shell.c:8:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char ***’
  int tokenizer(char *str,char **argv);
      ^
shell.c: At top level:
shell.c:64:6: error: conflicting types for ‘tokenizer’
  int tokenizer(char *str, char ***argv)
      ^
shell.c:8:6: note: previous declaration of ‘tokenizer’ was here
  int tokenizer(char *str,char **argv);

Comment: I was guessing my error was in way I allocating memory..    so, *** is an array of pointers to strings. wicked.    thank you